# VxWorks Terminal Continuous Read Variable

Tags: linux, unix, vxworks

In a VxWorks, I need to read the contents changes in a memory address, and I think I could read this using some sort of Unix syntax like.

In Unix, I'd use

```
tail -f < outputfile
```

So in VxWorks, I need to read the same way from

```
d 0x22221212
```

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is probably just to use the period function:

```
period 1, d, 0x22221212
```

Then every second the d function will get called with address 0x22221212 as a parameter.

http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/usrLib.html#period